# What does used com.Samsung.android.incallui mean in recent activity?

Tags: samsung

In my child’s recent activity it says
used com.Samsung.android.incallui. What does that mean?
Thanks so much!

Comment: `incallui` = incoming (or in/active) call user interface.

Answer (score 1):

It is the [phone/call](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/samsung-electronics-co-ltd/samsung-phone/samsung-phone-12-1-00-24-release/samsung-call-12-1-00-24-android-apk-download/) app. It simply means that the child opened it.